# Replace every odd element in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The code below replaces the odd elements of `arr` into symbols corresponding to them:

```
0 = '+'
1 = '-'
2 = '*'
3 = '/'
4 = '^'
```

so `12345` would turn into `1*3^5`.

**Code:**

```
sym = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
elements = 1
while elements < 5
  arr[elements] = sym[arr[elements]]
  elements += 2
end
puts "#{arr.join}"
```

I am looking for a more efficient replacement to this code.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?  Are you looking for computationally faster, or neater code?  I'm not sure you will find anything in terms of the former.

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify, I meant efficient as in computationally faster.

Comment: But if more efficient code is unavailable I would accept a neater code solution as an answer.

Comment: In terms of computational efficiency your code is really fast. Suppose you have N elements in array, to replace every odd characted you do N/2 iterations, in each iteration you do `O(1)` operation of lookup in array: `sym[arr[elements]]`. So your total complexity is `O(N/2) = O(N)` which is linear time.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by replacing the odd elements. In your example, precisely the **even** elements are replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could spiff-up your method as follows:

```
(1...arr.size).step(2).each { |i| arr[i] = sym[arr[i]] }
arr.join
  #=> "1*3^5"
```

Here's another way:

```
arr.each_slice(2).flat_map { |x,y| y ? [x, sym[y]] : [x] }.join
  #=> "1*3^5"
```

And another:

```
enum = [true, false].cycle
arr.map { |e| enum.next ? e : sym[e] }.join
  #=> "1*3^5"
```

Your method mutates (modifies) `arr`. Do you want to do that? The last two methods do not (but could be easily modified to do so).

Which of these three methods is best? You tell me!

Comment: Third one is the best :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find a *faster* solution, but you may find a more elegant one.  This is how I'd approach this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sym = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '^']
arr.map!.with_index { |value, idx| idx.odd? ? sym[idx] : value }
```

This has the same effect as your code, but it should work on arrays of any size (provided they are the same length).